# How to deploy windows service on Azure App Service

Tags: azure, windows-services, azure-web-app-service

I have developed a **windows service**. i need to deploy it in **Azure App Service**. Please someone explain me how to do that. Is there any way to install it on console or any other option.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't deploy a Windows Service using App Service.  One option is to convert your code into a [Web Job](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/).  Another option is to use a Virtual Machine instead of App Service.

Comment: Thankz for your reply...This window service listen to database changes sql server then it generates and modifies text files in local system. you mean this can't migrate to Azure app service..?? Can i use same executable files of my service to Web job? This is really complicated.. can you please explain me about this..

Comment: I developed the same program as a webjob and deployed. it works like a charm

Comment: @DimuthLochana  You should write a basic "how to" and post it to a blog...or append your question with "Here's what I did" and post some tidbits.  #giveBackToTheCommunityThatHelpsYouManyTimes

Answer (score 6):

Azure App Service is the service that should be used for Web/Mobile and basically is the web-server-as-a-service. You have almost no access to the underlying system, and system-wide actions like a working windows service is likely impossible.

I see three ways:

1) Migrate to Worker Role, but it is classic model. There is a [good article](https://alexandrebrisebois.wordpress.com/2015/02/22/lift-and-shift-of-a-windows-service-to-microsoft-azure/) on how to do that, i took a look and did not see any potential problems. It is more simple way.

2) Migrate your windows service to Web Job and run it as a background service. It will need you to rewrite some parts of your service, i think - but there are supported executable formats out-of-the-box. [Take a look at how it works.](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/)

3) Take a look at [Azure Functions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/functions/) - it is "trigger-and-invoke" service that can be used for listening for events and executing actions.

But, if you need to catch some events from DB, then i am not sure that it will be possible with that, because Web Job is more like a service that listens for external events, and yours scenario looks like you want to catch events from the same server. That way, i would recommend you to place it on a virtual machine to avoid the rewriting or migrating time-consuming issues.